# VS 2017 - TFS source controlled projects keep getting converted automatically to Git source controlled projects

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc, source-control-bindings

I have existing projects source controlled by TFS that I have done check-ins on, then when I do a check-in all of a sudden it’s source controlled by Git and it creates a local git repository for it and I can’t get back to my TFS source control.

How do I get control of my project source control back?

Comment: I'd suspect that there is a `.git` directory in the solution root folder or any of its parent folders. That's the sure-fire way to get Visual Studio to keep switching to Git from any other source control provider, including TFVC.

Comment: -Jessehouwing. I have deleted the git files several times, but I went to check again and decided to look for hidden folders, there was an entire hidden git folder that when I deleted it allowed me to add my project back to TFS!  Do you have any tips as to how to avoid this "git take-over" in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I deleted all the .git files in my solution as well as a "hidden" folder as suggested by jessehouwing. Then I also removed the "GitHub extension for Visual Studio" from my VS installation by doing the following in VS: 
Tools -> Get Tools and Features (let the VS Installer load) -> Individual Components -> un-check "GitHub extension for Visual Studio" -> Modify